# Why c++ game doesn't work with a timer?

Tags: c++

What would be the best way to add a chronometer because this type of chronometer that I invented makes my game snake advance in 1 second and its really slow

```
void timer()
{
    int g = 1;
    int h = 0;
    while (g != 0)
    {

    Sleep(1000);
    h = h + 1;
    gotoxy(50, 1); printf("Tiempo: %d",h);
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on what you expect. Your function pauses for a second because you asked it to, that's what `Sleep(1000);` does.

Comment: How can I make my system know what a second is?

Comment: That loop you show is *infinite*.

Comment: As for your problem, in your main loop, get the current time. If the difference between the current time and the previous current time is X then do Y.

Comment: With a [`clock`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/clock/).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek The `clock` function is specified to give a value representing the elapsed CPU time of a process. It doesn't do that on all systems. And it can be wrong in e.g. multi-threaded processes. C++ have very good [date and *time* functionality in the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) that are far more suitable.

Comment: void timer()
{
 time_t t = time(0);
 int g = 0;
 t = g;
 int contador = 0;
 if (t != g)
  contador = contador + 1;
  gotoxy(50, 1); printf("Tiempo: %d",contador);
 
 
}

Comment: I don't know how to do it :(

Answer (score 1):

Some pseudo-code to give you an idea of how it could be done:

```
time_type last_time = now();  // Initialize to the current time

// Main game loop
forever
{
    // Do other game-related things...

    // Now handle things that should be done on regular intervals
    time_type current_time = now();
    time_diff_type difference = current_time - last_time;

    if (difference > 2 second)
    {
        // Do things that should be done every two seconds
    }

    if (difference > 1 second)
    {
        // Do things that should be done every second
    }

    last_time = current_time;
}
```

For the `time_type` and `now` functions, use the functionality in [`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono).

For example, to get the current time do e.g.

```
auto current_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
```

And with a newer compiler and a `using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;` you could actually use e.g. `1s` as a second:

```
auto difference = current_time - last_time;
if (difference > 1s) { /* Code here... */ }
```

The above is valid C++ code.

Comment: I don't understand that I tried to do it like this can you help me please

Comment: void timer()
{
 time_t current = time(0);
 time_t currenta = time(0);
 currenta = currenta + 1;
 time_t resta = currenta - current;
 int g = 0;
 if (resta == 1)
  g = g + 1;
 gotoxy(50, 1); printf("Tiempo: %d", g);
}